# Want MediaPlayer to continue running when screen is locked

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

How could I make it so that my MediaPlayer continues to play even when the phone is locked and the screen is off, thinking it may have to do something of making it a service but not sure. If so how could I go about changing it to a service or is there a quicker easier fix?

Any help would be great!

Here is code:

```
 public class player2 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_2);
        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound04;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound05;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound06;
        // Listeners
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player2.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); ;         
             progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
             progressBar.setProgress(0);
             progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
             new Thread(this).start();

         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
            }
        });

        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 // No need to check if it is pauseicon

        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
         ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);

        } else {
            mp.start();
            ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
     }}});

   }
   static boolean runThread = true;
   public void run() {
        while ( runThread )  {
              int currentPosition=0;
              int total = mp.getDuration();
              if ( mp != null && currentPosition <= total )  {
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 return;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 return;
              }            
              progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
           } else
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        runThread = false; 
    }
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
           mp.pause();

       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume()
   {
   super.onResume();

   if (mp != null){
         if(!mp.isPlaying())
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             mp.start();

     }
   } 


   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow my tutorial below...In following tutorial i have stored .mp3 file in raw folder. if you have stored it in sd card and dynamically fetching that file then put its path in bundle and send it through intent which you can get in `onStartCommand()` method of your service.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  Button startPlaybackButton, stopPlaybackButton;
  Intent playbackServiceIntent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startPlaybackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartPlaybackButton);
    stopPlaybackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StopPlaybackButton);

    startPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundAudioService.class);
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == startPlaybackButton) {
      startService(playbackServiceIntent);
      finish();
    } else if (v == stopPlaybackButton) {
      stopService(playbackServiceIntent);
      finish();
    }
  }
}
```

BackgroundAudioService.java

```
public class BackgroundAudioService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc);// YOUR FILE NAME
          mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
          Log.v("TEST", "1");
      }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

         if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
             Log.v("TEST", "2");
          mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
      }

      public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
          mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
      }

      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
      }

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Background Audio Player"
        />
   <Button android:text="Start Playback" android:id="@+id/StartPlaybackButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
   <Button android:text="Stop Playback" android:id="@+id/StopPlaybackButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to declare Service in manifest.xml like below,

```
<service android:name="com.demo.tute.BackgroundAudioService" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this but what will happen to the random audio picker and the progress bar?

Comment: So you need to choose audio randomly after finishing one right? If so, It's quite simple Just create Arraylist of all audio file names or ids and use Collection.shuffle() method for shuffling them and in onCompletion() method in above service start other audio.

Comment: can you be specific about progress bar scenario??

Comment: Well the code I have works atm, it randomly picks an audio and plays it showing a progress bar, that works. The problem is I just want it so when I press the lock on phone it will continue playing.

Comment: How can i pass intent in onStartCommand(), because I am playing a file from SD card. Please help me out. @Melbourne Lopes

Comment: when you start the service using startService(yourIntent) method from activity, its onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) gets called in which you will get yourIntent.